# Setting content offset of dynamically expanding scroll view

Tags: objective-c

My app dynamically generates items onto a scroll view. Since there is not definite height for the scroll view, it keeps adding to its height after a condition. However, I can only fit 12 items on the screen, so I want it to scroll down automatically to the lowest part of the screen when `items%12==0;`. After doing some research, I learned about contentOffset. However, I'm not getting the behavior I want, it scrolls all the way to the top and freezes, until I add 12 more items to the screen. Here are my conditionals.

```
if (itemsLength %2 ==0) {

xPos = 20;
yPos += 60;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,scrollViewHeight+=50)];
NSLog(@"%i",scrollViewHeight);


}
if (itemsLength %12 == 0) {

CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0,self.scrollView.contentSize.height -  self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];


}
```

Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

EDIT: Is there a way to scroll to a certain point in my Scrollview, without changing the content offset? Doing so ruins the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (itemsLength %12 == 0) {

[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,scrollViewHeight-50,320,50) animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, xPos is for the item placement, and it isn't a constant, this didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: try the updated answer.That may work.To scroll to the bottom we need to specify the height of UIScrollView content

Comment: Thanks! This works partially, but I'd tried this before, and there's a small problem. When the itemsLength reaches 14, it goes all the way back to the top

Comment: Since my scrollview expands dynamically, can I keep increasing the offset in the "%2" condition?

Comment: I believe scrollViewHeight changes according to the height of scrollview changes

So instead of setContentOffset can you try scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,scrollViewHeight-50,320,50)

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work, but I'll have to play around with the numbers. It's exactly what I wanted though. Thanks much!!!